# TSQL Syntax, Replace Existing "Wrong Value" with previous "Correct Value"

Tags: t-sql

I have an application that makes an entry every hour in a MS SQL database.
The last entry on the 12th FEB is a zero value and is showing in my weekly report.

What I want to do is take the value from the previous count and enter into the filed instead of the zero value.

Can someone offer some advice on how to this because it is beyond my TSQL skills?

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[CountDetails]
WHERE [updateTime] < '2013-02.13'
AND [updateTime] > '2013-02.12'
AND ( DATEPART(hh,[updateTime])= '22' OR DATEPART(hh,[updateTime])= '23' )
```

[image: SQL Results from query]

Note: The application is supposed to zero the count a Midnight but on the 12th FEB it happened early and I know why.

EDIT: There are 5 IP addresses in total and 6 counters in total because 192.168.168.11 has 2 counters. So 2111 to 2116 is an entire entry for all available counters at 22:58 and 2117 to 2122 is an entire entry for all available counters at 23:58. I need to replace the 23:58 values with the corresponding value from 22:58.

Comment: Since you do not know the correct count for ID's 2117 to 2122 wouldnt the count for them items be assigned to 151?

Comment: I'm reading this as 2117 should be 576, 2118 should be 85, 2119 should be 246, etc.  IE, same for same description.  But OP should certainly clarify that.

Comment: @Joe ah yes if you split it by description. I assumed from the last entry in the DB.

Comment: Don't have time to do a full solution, but I think you can use the id, and say something like, update table T set count=(select count from table E where E.description=T.description and E.id<T.id group by description having max(E.id).  Slightly more complex than that, but using that idea.

Comment: Yes Guys, I need 2117 to be 576 and 2118 to be 85 etc. There are 6 counters in total. 192.168.168.11 has 2 counters and the other 4 IP's have 1 counter each. So I need to take the top values, as a group, and mirror them in the group below.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing here, but an update that joins on the `ipAddress`, `counterNumber`, and the `datetime` excluding fractional seconds, separated by an hour (do the `SELECT` part first for safety):

```
UPDATE b
SET count = a.count
-- SELECT *
FROM dbo.CountDetails a
JOIN dbo.CountDetails b ON a.ipAddress = b.ipAddress AND a.counterNumber = b.counterNumber
AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),b.updateTime,120) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),DATEADD(HOUR,1,a.updateTime),120)
```

Comment: I can only get it to set all the [COUNT] entries to the same value threw out the Table. I'm having trouble defining which entries to take from and then to update to. Must be what is meant by the "--SELECT * ". Thanks, I'll keep at it.